# Evaluating $\dfrac{1}{\Gamma (r)}\int_{0}^{x}(x-t)^{\alpha -1}t^{\lambda}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function

How can I evaluate  the following integral

$$\frac1{\Gamma(r)}\int_0^x(x-t)^{\alpha-1}t^\lambda\ dt$$

Comment: If you substitute $t = x\cdot u$, do you recognise what you get?

Comment: You're a short substitution away from the beta function

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $t=xy\;\color{blue}{\Rightarrow}\;dt=x\ dy$, the integral turns out to be
$$
\frac1{\Gamma(r)}\int_0^1(x-xy)^{\alpha-1}(xy)^\lambda x\ dy=\frac{x^{\alpha+\lambda}}{\Gamma(r)}\int_0^1(1-y)^{\alpha-1}y^\lambda \ dy,
$$
then you may refer to [Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).
$$
\frac1{\Gamma(r)}\int_0^x(x-t)^{\alpha-1}t^\lambda\ dt=\frac{x^{\alpha+\lambda}}{\Gamma(r)}\cdot\text{B}\left(\alpha,\lambda+1\right)=\frac{x^{\alpha+\lambda}}{\Gamma(r)}\cdot\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\lambda+1)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\lambda+1)}.
$$